# Integração em bancos

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, microsoft-access, codeigniter-2

Boa tarde! Preciso de uma orientação/sugestão. É o seguinte: temos um software do relógio onde ele gravar todas as marcações em um banco de dados em  MS Access. Preciso criar um relatório de cada funcionário na intranet da empresa, onde a mesma é em PHP e MySQL usando framework Codeigniter. Gostaria de saber se o ideal seria sincronizar o banco de dados MS Access com o MySQL e se isso é possível. Eu preciso consultar o dados no MS Access e também gravar algumas informações nele. Eu tentei criar uma nova conexão dentro do próprio codeigniter com Access, mas não obtive sucesso. Se alguém puder me orientar por favor.

Comment: Você pode criar uma rotina para enviar os dados do Access para o [MySQL via ODBC](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/odbc/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sim é possível integrar o Access no PHP através do PDO, basta a `connectionString` correta. Mas você também pode usar o CI. Veja [esta resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14274274/codeigniter-using-ms-access-database) para ter uma base de como configurar a conexão dentro dele.

Outras threads abaixo podem te ajudar também

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/178860/how-do-i-add-an-msaccess-connection-to-codeigniter-or-cakephp
- https://forum.codeigniter.com/thread-429.html

Mas se a intranet é em MySQL, creio que seria mais viável utilizá-lo ao invés do OleDb, e ele é muito mais robusto também. A outra opção é também criar um job para fazer o envio para o MySQL, mas neste caso você precisaria disponibilizar a conexão aberta e criar um outro script que faria este envio.

De qualquer forma as duas maneiras são válidas, porém seria mais vantajoso ter tudo em um único banco de dados.